# Running program for all my tests file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using Linux for executing my program, **my_program**, following the next syntax:

```
./my_program <arg>
```

My program expect an input from user to proceed.

For testing purposes I have a **tests.txt** file with all my test cases (a test per line). I run the program then:

```
./my_program <arg> < tests.txt
```

It works good only for the first line of my tests file, but I want to know if a bash command  exists to execute my program for all the lines in tests file?

Comment: Redirection sends all the lines of the file to the program's standard input, not just the first line.

Comment: Is there any chance your program might not handle input from stdin correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your program only runs one test case at a time. So you need to do:

```
while read line
do echo "$line" | ./my_program <arg>
done < tests.txt
```

Comment: Why pipe to the program and not `./my_program "$line"`?

Comment: Because the program is expecting to read input from the user on stdin.